# How to determine the precise model of an "AMD Radeon R7 200 Series"

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, amd-radeon

Device Manager, Belarc Advisor, and even AMD Settings app show my video card only as "AMD Radeon R7 200 Series".

I'm trying to determine whether card fully supports FreeSync, and so I need to know the specific model number, but I'm having difficulty finding that using the utilities mentioned above.

How else would I go about finding the specific model number for this card?

Comment: Unless you identify what card you actually have, we won't be able to identify, if it supports FreeSync.  Sounds like you should, remove the card, and look at the label on the card.

Comment: @Ramhound The problem is exactly how I can identify the card. Of course, taking it out is an option, but shouldn't the system have the information?

Comment: @Ramhound Though I should have mentioned in the question that I did find https://support.amd.com/en-us/search/faq/219 and wanted to know how to identify the card more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

[GPU-Z](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/gpu-z/) does provide the more precise information I needed; though the name is shown same as elsewhere, `Lookup` button shows the card is R7 260X, which has full FreeSync support.